# Put a stack params to a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, parameters, cocos2d-x

I view this code at CCArmatureDataManager.cpp 253 line. RelativeData is a struct.Here, put a stack param into a map. Why, no problem?? Is there someone explain this to me? thx!!!

```
struct RelativeData
{
    std::vector<std::string> plistFiles;
    std::vector<std::string> armatures;
    std::vector<std::string> animations;
    std::vector<std::string> textures;
};

void CCArmatureDataManager::addRelativeData(const std::string& configFilePath)
{
    if (_relativeDatas.find(configFilePath) == _relativeDatas.end())
    {
        _relativeDatas[configFilePath] = RelativeData();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you put something in a map, you *copy* it.

Comment: What type params will be copyed??? Like function's params???

Comment: The map has it's own entries of "things". So if you have a map of `RelativeData`, then a copy of the  (temporary)  object of `RelativeData` type will get stored in the map.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

```
_relativeDatas[configFilePath] = RelativeData()
```

The `RelativeData()` part creates a temporary default-constructed object.

The `_relativeDatas[configFilePath]` part calls [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) which returns a *reference* to an object.

The assignment *copies* from the temporary object to the object whose reference the `[]` operator returned. In other words, the `RelativeData` [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) is called (the compiler will in most cases create one for you if you don't have one).

If there is no element with the key `configFilePath`, then the map will default construct one, and return a reference to it.

So what your code does is create two default-constructed objects of type `RelativeData`, and copies the contents from one to the other. It is, in maybe not so kind words, pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the function simply adds, if not already there, an empty struct to the _relativeDatas map ( which is most seemingly a std::map < std::String configFile, struct RelativeData > ), which can then be filled with data